# Process cannot access file because it is in use by another program

Tags: batch-file, ping

I am trying to write a script to ping an ip range and return a .txt report of active ip's to use as a variable, to copy an updated folder to all active terminals.
I have fallen at the first hurdle as the script runs but displays error message " the process cannot access the file because it is in use by another program."
My script is as follows.

```
 @echo off
 :start
 FOR /L %%a in (1,1,255) do @(
 echo pinging ip range: 172.26.8.%%a
 ping -n 1 -w 500 172.26.8.%%a | FIND /i "Reply">>PTEST.txt
 )
 )
 echo ***Scan complete.***
 pause
 end
```

I have tried adding 2<&1after PTEST.txt but still the same result.

Comment: Besides a superfluous `)`, to redirect also the _STDERR_ stream, use `2>&1`...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using STDERR redirection for IP's which do not exist in that range, but there should be no obvious reason that `PTEST.txt` should be in use from what you've posted.

You do however appear to have unbalanced parentheses though, so if what you've posted is actually part of another `For`/`If` block, you should show the rest of the script.

```bat
@Echo Off
(   For /L %%A In (1,1,255) Do (
        Echo Pinging IP address: 172.26.8.%%A
        Ping -n 1 -w 500 172.26.8.%%A 2>Nul|Find /I "Reply"
    )
)>"PTEST.txt"
Echo ***Scan complete.***
Pause
```

Comment: I have only just started this batch but the idea was to obtain a list of active terminals and the call on another process or batch to del an existing folder containing out of date information then copy an updated folder to the same location. Any information or advice on completing this would be greatly recieved

Comment: @PBlank22, I'm sorry, I don't do requests, if you have another question then feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Thats cool thanks for your help so far will try the above for now thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your batch jobs name is "ping.bat" and you call

```
 Ping -n 1 -w 500 172.26.8.%%A 2>Nul|Find /I "Reply"
```

so your ping.bat is calles instead of ping.exe.

Change the line to

```
Ping.exe -n 1 -w 500 172.26.8.%%A 2>Nul|Find /I "Reply"
```